# AngularJS - Angular Routing App

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angularjs-routing

I have a Angular Application, in a main.js file i have defined the app routing but i have a doubt, for example, i have a accodion  menu of bootstrap, when i click about the next button:

```
<a href="#MainMenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="img/ico_menu_off.png" /></a>
```

Due to the angular's configuration routes, the atributte href="#MainMenu", it recognizes it as a route and I not want to do anything.

This is the js code:

```
angularRoutingApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/customerSearch', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/customer-search.html',
            controller  : 'customerSearchController'
        })      
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

How could resolved this? thanks, (i'm new in Angular)

Comment: Did you set  `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in your app config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `href` attribute to select accordion in your case, because it will change the URL directly as you are using anchor's `href`. To solve problem you should use `data-target` attribute instead of `href`

**Markup**

```
<a data-target="#MainMenu" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#MainMenu" class="dropdown-toggle">
   <img src="img/ico_menu_off.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the href and open it with JavaScript on click:

```
$("#MainMenuTrigger").click(function(){
     $('#MainMenu').modal();
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api

I suggest you also to give a look to [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

Answer (score 1):

you could remove hash from URL. find this URL it will help you
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1063634/Removing-the-sharp-Sign-from-AngularJS-URLs-with-I